# ModuleNotFoundError when using importlib.import_module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have the following folder structure and I have a test method in util.py. When the util method is run, I see an error with a module that is imported within the module where I am trying to get all classes.

```
Parent
--report <dir>
----__init__.py
----AReport.py
----names_list.py
--util.py
```

util.py

```
import inspect
import importlib
import importlib.util

def get_class_names(fileName):
    for name, cls in inspect.getmembers(importlib.import_module(fileName, package='report'), inspect.isclass):
        print(name, cls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_class_names('report.names_list')
```

names_list.py

```
from AReport import AReport

class Team:
    name = ""
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Names_List(AReport):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        AReport.__init__(self, name)

    def test(self):
        print('In test')
```

AReport.py

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AReport(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name:
            self.name = name

    def test(self):
        pass
```

When I run my test method from util, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named AReport
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you did not change anything with `sys.path` or with `PYTHONPATH`, the problem is that `AReport` module is not "visible" from util.py.

You can check this by adding this at the top of `util.py`:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

That's going to print out a list of all paths where the interpreter will look for modules. You'll see that only the path to the `Parent` module is there, because this is where the `util.py` was run from. This is explained in [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) documentation:

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches
> for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
> for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the
> variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory
>   when no file is specified).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the
>   shell variable `PATH`).
> - The installation-dependent default.

When you run `util.py` from the Parent directory (= "*The directory containing the input script*"), and you do

```
from AReport import AReport
```

it will look for a `AReport` module from the Parent directory, but it's not there because only the `report` package is directly under the /path/to/Parent directory.

If you do instead

```
from report.AReport import AReport
```

it's going to work because the `report` package is under /path/to/Parent.

If you want to avoid the `report.` prefix when importing, one option is to add the `report` package to the `sys.path` on `util.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./report")

print(sys.path)
# should now show the /path/to/Parent/report on the list
```

Then your `from AReport` import will now work.

A much better option is to add /path/to/Parent/report to the [`PYTHONPATH` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) before running `util.py`.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/Parent/report
```

From the Python documentation:

> **PYTHONPATH**
>
> Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the same as the shell’s `PATH`: one or more directory pathnames
> separated by `os.pathsep` (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on
> Windows). Non-existent directories are silently ignored.

I usually go with the `PYTHONPATH` option, so that I don't need to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```py
from report.AReport import AReport
```

Comment: This is confusing, why do we have to import the class from folder when both the classes are in the same folder?

Comment: @dcu Gino wrote a great answer, but to make it short and simple: Because you run it from another folder.